# Image in div, center full size responsive

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have a div which change width depending on browser width, responsive. In the div is an image which in the broadest version of my site is closest to the original image regarding width/height.

When the browser window gets smaller I want the height of the image to remain but overflow of the width to be hidden. The image should be centered in the div. Is this possible?

1. Full size
2. Mobile version

Example http://postimg.org/image/v16lb0rft/

Comment: Do you know in advance the width of the image, or do you expect this to work with any image width?

Comment: Depending on how tricky it is I can stick to uploading images with the same width. If it is possible the width should be different.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, just use media queries. For example :

```
@media screen and (max-width: 640px) {
  #yourImage{
      overflow-x: hidden;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a great jQuery plugin called backstretch. Usually it's used to make full background images like [here (clothing website)](http://www.htfu.com). But it can also be used in a small div of any size.
[Backstretch.js](http://srobbin.com/jquery-plugins/backstretch/)

Answer (score 0):

If it's not a problem to hardcode the width of the image then this should work.

```
img#your-img {
    margin: 0 calc(50% - (/* the width of img#your-img */ / 2));
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

I hope this helps, good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I had been trying to find a solution to this for quite some time and finally came across this:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="image-wrapper">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x200">
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.image-wrapper {
    /* Height 0, padding-bottom, and overflow hidden
    give the wrapper height since it won't get a height
    from it's child being positioned absolutely */
    height:0;
    padding-bottom:65%;
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
    width:100%; /* your dimension here (can be px or %) */
}
.image-wrapper img {
    display:block;
    height:100%;
    left:50%;
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    width:auto;

    /* Negative translate instead of negative margins */
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

I've tested this and it works. If IE is important to you, you may be out of luck, but I hope this helps!

[Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mwfds60z/1/)